# I just had a e-cigarette at school and I got caught. I'm only 14 what should I do

Tags: education

At school a kid brought a e-cigarette to school and my friends pressured me to try it (that is where I should have walked away). I never actually inhaled I just put it to my mouth and said I did and then left. Later that day the principal found out and I got sent to the office and she said I could get suspended and they are going to tell my parents on Monday. I really messed up bad and I need help what should I do.

Comment: Explain everything to your parents and hope that they understand...

Comment: Better than being caught with an actual cigarette. Regulations have yet to prove e-cigs are just as horrid for you. Can't say what you should do regarding your parents, but in case you ever wondered what it's like trying to quit cigarettes, just imagine the feeling of being really hungry. That happens every 45 minutes in your throat when you are a smoker. Try to go 2 days without eating and see how hard it is to resist food. Quitting smoking is like starving, but it takes months upon months for the hunger to stop, and when it does, the thought stays with you. Never do it.

Comment: @KaiQing one minor nitpick: _regulations_ don't prove harm, _research_ does. (I think it's the case that both are lacking in regards to vaping, though.)

Comment: Yeah agreed. The conspiracy theorist part of me wants to say regulations exist to minimize insurance claims or some such and don't actually exist to protect people. Either way, addiction in all forms tend to have extreme difficulty in recovery. Some more than others. And clearly smoking is not one of the easier addictions to beat. E-gics not exempt of that. At least a cigarette is clear when you burnt it to the end. You could sit on an e-cig in one straight shot all day long and inhale a whole pack of nicotine without realizing it.

Comment: Get new friends.

Comment: Maybe it makes you feel better, but in my opinion at about four times your age, a principal that threatens you with suspension over smoking an e-cigarette should be looking for another job. The job of a school is to teach you things. Being suspended you are not going to learn. Suspending you means the school absolutely failed.

Comment: That said, do yourself, your health, and your wallet a huge, huge favour and never start smoking. It's about the worst waste of money possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it will involve the parents, it is not about the topic of parenting.

Answer (score 10):

**Learn from the experience.** Yes, that *is* when you should have walked away, and it's probably safe to say you'll be a lot more confident in yourself the next time a situation like this comes up.

**Explain the situation to your parents today** instead of waiting for the school to act (or instead of hoping they don't act). If my child was potentially getting suspended, I would want to hear about it as soon as possible. Keep as calm as possible. Is it going to be easy? I doubt it – but it's going to be harder if somebody else breaks the news and *then* you have the conversation.

**Be honest about it**, with both yourself and your parents. That includes both the negatives (you caved to peer pressure, broke the rules, the school is angry) and the positives (you didn't inhale, you aren't interested in e-cigarettes, it wasn't yours, you won't do this again, you've learned from the experience [of course, whichever of those is really true]). If you want their support in talking to the principal to explore an alternative punishment than suspension, you should aim to convince them that you're aware of the mistake and that you won't be repeating it.

Generally, you should try to be mature and calm throughout. Getting defensive, getting angry, trying to hide what happened... none of those are going to help you and your parents get through a tough conversation.